# how to get id of component(element) in react-native

Tags: react-native

quick question I am using react-native in one of my app and when I tried to get id of element **event.target.id** (like in React) somehow I am getting undefined maybe there is other way to get the id?

Comment: What's the use-case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a list of news through api wordpress and displaying posts.js.
Now I want to go to the post.js page by clicking on each item and displaying that particular item.

Comment: While this is not an answer, Please use comment section to ask additional or supplementary question. Thanks.